# How do I get to the center of the Mines of Avarice?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault

There's a big black hole in the middle of my Mines of Avarice map and I can't seem to uncover it. I've tried entering from the gated side in the canyon and from the dwarf fortress to no avail. I've tried hopping on the wall decorations, using the blue rune for extra melee power, solving the cube puzzle, and doing the other quests in the area. How do I uncover this last part?

Missing portion of map is near orange triangle in following map:

[image: Mines of Avarice]

Comment: I've done it and kinda remember it, but not enough to provide a full answer.  The area is at the top of the map, and I think there's a side quest that you need to be on in order to get there.  If memory serves, that quest comes from Marcus, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @MBraedley: Strange—I believe I've finished all the other quests

Comment: That shaded center area of the map contained nothing more than a short walk and a loot chest (which for me was a Mimic creature). I did get credit for discovering "Ingot Processing" (I think it was) when the shaded area's fog of war was lifted from the map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just accomplished this myself. Assuming you have already finished the main story mission for this area, return to the eastern portion of the map and kill the Gold Golem. Afterward you will notice the surrounding molten river will turn a greenish hue. Backtrack west to a small dwarven complex (which you had to pass through to reach the Gold Golem). You will notice a gate leading to the blocked area is now opened.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a shortcut back to the entrance if you go back and kill the gold golem a second time. Nothing interesting in there at all.